# dbwritetable from multiple R studio sessions to same SQL table concurrently

Tags: r, rstudio, dbi

I started 4 sessions from RStudio and I see 4 "R Studio R session" on the task manager. I connect to the same SQL database table in each session and dbwritetable using the same dsn name.

```
conn<-dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),"server",database="x_test")

dbWriteTable(conn,"x_testbl",export,overwrite=FALSE,append=TRUE)
```

Note that export is a data.table, it has the same columns as the SQL table being written to and each "export" table in the session will be relatively unique but some columns may have the same value (naturally).

I hope to perform multiple writes in each session concurrently. Each session performs some calculation and then dbwritetable writes the data.table to the SQL table. Would this cause any issues? Is there anything I could do to ensure no issues? Thanks!

Comment: @RYoda thanks for your response, please see edit above.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit)  Version: 13.0.4001.0

Comment: @RYoda I do this: I go to Session in RStudio & start "New Session". I do this 4 times. I see 4 "R Studio R session" in my task manager. I hope to run the same script in each session.

Comment: OK, I cannot see any reason why this should fail at the R side. The database is the handling the concurrent inserts and probably it is best to use transctions via `dbBegin` and `dbCommit` but it should not be required. I will do quick test using MS-SQL 2016...

Comment: @RYoda Thanks for your time! I hope to do 4 sessions so that I can write in parallel essentially and cut down on total time. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: which ODBC driver are you using? {SQL Server} or {SQL Server native Client 11.x}?

Comment: i made DSN using ODBC data source administrator (64bit): Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver Version 06.03.9600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If have tested your code on the same SQL Server 2016 version
using the `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` (I don't have your driver installed) and traced the SQL code executed at the server.

I am using the `iris` data set:

```
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris, overwrite = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

The `odbc` package basically issues these commands (a prepared statement):

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=9
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,N'@P1 float,@P2 float,@P3 float,@P4 float,@P5 varchar(255)',N'INSERT INTO "iris" ("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species")
VALUES (@P1, @P2, @P3, @P4, @P5)',1
select @p1

exec sp_execute 9,5.0999999999999996,3.5,1.3999999999999999,0.20000000000000001,'setosa'
[... multiple inserts...]

exec sp_unprepare 9
```

So there is no risk of running your code in parallel in multiple sessions beyond the usual SQL Server like non-deterministic insert order of the rows (possibly resulting in different autoinc values for the same inserted row if you try to reproduce the behaviour).

You will also have four open connections (no issue at all).

If your goal is insert performance could use different bulk insert methods of the SQL Server but the performance of `dbWriteTable` is excellent (if you use an up-to-date version).

For details of "bulk-uploads" via the `odbc` package see:

https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/34

**Added later:**

> each "export" table in the session will be relatively unique
>   but some columns may have the same value (naturally).

If your target table does not have a primary key it is no problem
to insert duplicated rows (until you want to re-identify single
rows but this is pure SQL problem). You could add an ID row to your `data.table`s using the high-low pattern to solve this (high = a unique value for each session, low = an R sequence from `1:NROW(data)` then add the high value, eg. "10000000" so that the overall IDs are unique all over your sessions - but have gaps of course).

Answer (score 0):

This could cause issues if multiple sessions are trying to update the same record at the same time.  One of the sessions could lock the record so the other session cannot update it.
You can have a single session which does all of the transactions instead of 4 sessions.